# How to iterate over a range in descending order without modifying the range

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, output, stdvector

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to get access to elements in descending order. I cannot modify input data, so `std::sort` is not an option.

I've tried to use `std::max_element`, but when it is equal to `std::begin()`, somehow I can't find the lowest value of the current max. Why is that?

```cpp
const std::vector<int> v{2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 4, 3, 2};
auto max = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
auto min = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
auto tmp = std::begin(v);

while(*max != *min)
{
    tmp = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(),
        [max](const auto& item1, const auto& item2)
        {
            return item2 < *max && item1 < item2;
        });
    max = tmp;        
}
```

Comment: If it's not too much data, you could copy it, and then sort the copy?

Comment: You could also create an index vector and sort that (with a comparator that looks up values in the original array)

Comment: data i used is just example, i try to find the most efficient way to get accest to such elements having just input data, also forget to mention that if the lowest element is at the beginnig the it works even if the rest is not sorted

Comment: The "most efficient" way involves a constant amount of traversals (ie sorting the input, or sorting an index vector), not traversing the input for *every* element.

Comment: This homework assignment or practice problem must be designed to test a specific programming topic or algorithm that needs to be employed to accomplish this task. What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from?

Comment: You are on the right track but the logic inside the `while` loop is broken, specially on the **Capture Clause** of your lambda expression, Hence your problem.

Comment: @AzrielElijay What is wrong with the capture clause? It is [copied](https://cppinsights.io/s/8b2277a6) into the lambda each iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: Please add `int main()` and missing `#include`s.

Comment: @Mestkon Aside from iterator invalidation , the whole logic is tied into `max` and what if `max` is from one of two or more elements of equal value(given the logic of his `while` loop and within it.)

Answer (score 5):

Just copy and sort. It will be much more efficient than trying to do something inline without modifying the original container, especially for larger data sets.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> descending_order(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    auto copy = vec;
    std::sort(copy.begin(), copy.end(), std::greater<int>());
    return copy;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 4, 3, 2};
    auto correct_order = descending_order(v);

    // prints '6 5 4 4 3 2 2 1 0 '
    for (auto val : correct_order) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you do this, then you may as well make the copy at the call site by having the function take in the vector by value instead of by reference: `std::vector<int> descending_order(std::vector<int> vec) { std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<int>()); return vec; }`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect at least because the code will output nothing when a vector contains equal elements due to the condition of the while loop

```
while(*max != *min)
```

Also if at least two elements are equal in the vector then the return statement in the used lambda within the while loop

```
return item2 < *max && item1 < item2;
```

will not return the iterator that points to the second equal element.

A simple approach is to use one more container that will store copies of elemnets of the original vector in the descending order.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v { 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 4, 3, 2 };

    //  make a block scope to destroy the set after exiting the block
    {
        std::multiset<int, std::greater<>> s( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );

        for (const auto &item : s)
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    //... 
}
```

The program output is

```
6 5 4 4 3 2 2 1 0
```

Without using an additional container you will need to define your own algorithm `max_element_if` like for example

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIterator max_element_if( ForwardIterator first, 
                                ForwardIterator last,
                                UnaryPredicate unary_predicate )
{
    auto max = first;

    while (max != last && !unary_predicate( *max )) ++max;

    for (auto current = max; current != last; ++current)
    {
        if (unary_predicate( *current ) && *max < *current) max = current;
    }

    return max;
}
```

By the way such an algorithm should be included in the standard C++ library.:)

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIterator max_element_if( ForwardIterator first, 
                                ForwardIterator last,
                                UnaryPredicate unary_predicate )
{
    auto max = first;

    while (max != last && !unary_predicate( *max )) ++max;

    for (auto current = max; current != last; ++current)
    {
        if (unary_predicate( *current ) && *max < *current) max = current;
    }

    return max;
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{ 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 4, 3, 2 };

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator max = std::max_element( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );

    do
    {
        auto n = std::count( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), *max );

        while (n--) std::cout << *max << ' ';

    } while (( max = ::max_element_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
        [max]( const auto &item ) { return item < *max; } ) ) != std::end( v ));

    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

The program output is the same as shown above that is

```
6 5 4 4 3 2 2 1 0
```

At last if you have a vector of very complex and large objects making copies of which is resorce consuming then you could create a vector of references to objects using standard class `std::reference_wrapper` and sort it.

Here is one more demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{ 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6, 4, 3, 2 };

    //  make a block scope to destroy the additional vector after exiting the block
    {
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> indices;
        indices.reserve( v.size() );

        for (const auto &item : v) indices.push_back( std::cref( item ) );

        std::sort( std::begin( indices ), std::end( indices ), std::greater<>() );

        for (const auto &item : indices)
        {
            std::cout << item.get() << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // ...
}
```